# Seemingly incorrect timezone conversion in MySQL (UTC to PST)

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

The current timezone in my MySQL server is UTC:

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
```

prints `UTC, UTC`

At `4:00 AM PST, on Jan 08, 2016` when my cron executed the following statement:

```
select DATE(DATE_SUB(CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE(),'UTC','America/Los_Angeles'), INTERVAL 5 DAY))
```

It got `2016-01-02` as the answer. Should it not give me `2016-01-03` since I am substracting  `INTERVAL 5 DAYS` from `2016-01-08`?

Answer (score 0):

You can set timezone for database connection and use this TZ-mode for other queries:

```
SET time_zone '+00:00'
```